# High school solid geometry

Tags: geometry

I need help with a pair of questions. I've attempted these questions as shown below.

Question 7 - Diagram shows 4 similar bowls with the shape of a hemisphere arranged to touch each other. The volume of each bowl is $\frac {9π}{4} cm^3$. Find length of PQ.

> Attempt: I've done $\frac {9}{4}π = \frac {2}{3}πr^3$. Got $r = \frac{3}{2}$ and hence PQ = 6. But answer is different.

Question 10 - Diagram shows a solid made up of a right circular cylinder and a hemisphere. Find $r$ if both the right circular cylinder and the hemisphere have the same volume.

> Attempt: I did $\frac {2}{3}πr^3 = πr^2h$. Got r = 12

Image for question 7:

[image: Question 7]

Image for question 10:

[image: Question 10]

Comment: Please don't post your HW's here.

Comment: These question you can do with Q7) Apply the formula for the volume. Q10) Try to make a linear equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q.7,

We have $$PQ=8r=\frac{3}{2}\times8=12$$

For Q.10, your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks so much! Silly mistake on radius